# jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave problems, keep toggled div shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have got 1 area, and on mouseenter I am fading in the following div:

```
$( "area.hasmore" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).next(".popup").stop().fadeIn();
});
```

Let's say the popup appears on the right hand side. What if the user leaves the area on the left hand side? Let's fade that popup out:

```
$( "area.hasmore, .popup" ).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".popup").fadeOut(); 
});
```

Here comes my problem: users should be able to move the cursor into the fresh opened popup to the right and maybe even click a link in there. My problem is that it fades out due to the mouseleave event on the area. One problem might be the fact that the popup is no child. As a child of the area hovering the popup would still count as being 'inside' the area I guess. So I am kind of trying to find out how to keep the popup visible when mouseentering it and mouseleaving the area.
Here's the code:

```
<area class="hasmore" />
<div class="popup">...
```

Sry if I missed a question where this exact problem is being discussed.

jsfiddle here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8o9kv487/1/)

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: thanks, never made one. was about time

Comment: I'm guessing you can't change the markup to have the popup as a child of the area?

Comment: Guessed right; I'll add this to the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manage what is visible in the `hover` instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

Something like this:

```
$('div').hover(function () {
    console.log(this.className);
    if (this.className === 'hasmore') {
        $(this).next(".popup").stop().fadeIn();
    } else if (this.className !== 'hasmore' && this.className !== 'popup') {
        $(".popup").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/yvqv67dw/1/)

Comment: While both answers are pretty good, I like yours more because it's 'cleaner' and there is no need to update my code. But right now it's not working: my fiddle was bad, I forgot to add the area instead of that first div. With area your code is not working. Any idea? I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvqv67dw/2/

Comment: The original example i posted was only looking at `div` elements.  Adding `area` got it working for me.  [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sfmjy1s/)

Comment: Oh, I tried it with area only. Well that makes sense, thanks a lot for that nice solution. Also thanks to bitfhacker!

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div class="hasmore">hover me</div>
<div class="popup">Popup 1</div>

<div class="evenmore">stuff</div>
<div class="popup">2nd popup. don't mind me</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $( ".container" ).mouseenter(function() {
     $(".popup").stop().fadeIn();
 });

$( "div.container" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".popup").fadeOut();
});
```

CSS (include this)

```
.container {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The trick is to create a div (.container) with display: block and enclosure .hasmore and .popup inside it!